# Pink, Black, then Nothing?

Tags: startup, restart

Previous thread found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/715174/screen-turns-pink-then-black

In this thread I was having an issue, then it was randomly fixed. After more playing around with it, I get a 1/20th chance of it actually doing this process then showing the login menu. I am just wondering before I try reinstalling, has anyone else had issues with this? It is completely random and when I try to restart usually it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing important I would suggest reinstalling.. however if it is some sort of problem with your hardware it may be the same after the reinstall.

Good luck!